# Extending File Comparer, GetHashCode method

Tags: c#

I am trying to extend File Comparer, to substract root paths from path of files being compared. The problem is in `GetHashCode()` method as I have two different root paths (root_a and root_b). How to implement it properly that corresponding root pats are assigned to the right file?

```
class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{
    string m_root_a;
    string m_root_b;
    public FileCompare() { }
    public FileCompare(string root_a, string root_b) 
    { 
        m_root_a = root_a; 
        m_root_b = root_b; 
    }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.FullName.Substring(m_root_a.Length) == 
            f2.FullName.Substring(m_root_b.Length) && 
            f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = $"{fi.FullName.Substring(m_root_a.Length)}{fi.Length}";
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Code for testing the comparer:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Dir Compare Tmp\\dir1\\");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Dir Compare Tmp\\dir2\\");

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", 
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", 
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare("C:\\Dir Compare Tmp\\dir1\\", 
    "C:\\Dir Compare Tmp\\dir2\\");

bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);

List<string> commonFilesList = new List<string>();
List<string> files1OnlyList = new List<string>();
List<string> files2OnlyList = new List<string>();

var queryCommonFiles = list1.Intersect(list2, myFileCompare);
var queryList1Only = (from file in list1 select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);
var queryList2Only = (from file in list2 select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare);

foreach (var v in queryCommonFiles)
    commonFilesList.Add(v.FullName);

foreach (var v in queryList1Only)
    files1OnlyList.Add(v.FullName);

foreach (var v in queryList2Only)
    files2OnlyList.Add(v.FullName);
```

Update: Unfortunately code does not work properly when I have different length of root paths e.g. second path `C:\\Dir Compare Tmp\\dir2 - Copy\\`. I get no files in commonFilesList (using GetHashCode implementation from the answer; fails Equals function). What would be solution for this, or should I use different approach to compare files? This will be used to compare large amount of files, therefore code latency is important.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Does it work when you use `return 1;` in the `GetHashCode()` method?

Comment: It feels like a bug that you're using two different string lengths for comparison in `Equals` (`m_root_a` and `m_root_b`), but only one of them in `GetHashCode` (`m_root_a`).

Comment: You can get the "root path" from the `FileInfo` object itself by subtracting `Name` from `FullName`. What is the purpose of storing the "root paths"?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. Seeing as this is an `IEqualityComparer`, its only job should be to compare files. Storing data should happen elsewhere.

Comment: @Progman - Yes it does, provides same correct result.

Comment: @CreekDrop You get already the correct result? I have tested your code and in fact it gets the correct result. What is the question you have?

Comment: @Progman, the question is how to proceed with this method properly. I am not sure what it does however it has to be implemented by the interface member. And I have two different root paths.

Comment: @CreekDrop Your implementation of `Equals()` is broken anyway. When you provide directory paths with different string lengths it might fail as you get `FileInfo` instances from a "random" directory, which doesn't correspond with `m_root_a.Length` (or `m_root_b.Length`). It only works because you have a `GetHashCode()` implementation, which also is kinda broken or doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rufus L, root paths are paths of directories which are compared. They are different but folder structure inside can be same and this is checked by comparer.

Comment: @CreekDrop You don't need these root paths in your comparer. Instead you can just use the condition `f1.Name == f2.Name && f1.Length == f2.Length` to say: "if they have the same name and the same size, they are the same".

Comment: Hopefully you see that storing two different root paths, with potentially different lengths, is going to mess up the equality comparison since the items being compared in the `Equals` method are not necessarily going to be in order, where the first file is from the first root and vice  versa.

Answer (score 1):

As your comparer is already storing both the root paths and only the files in those paths are expected to be passed to GetHashCode method, I hope the following implementation will get done what you want to achieve.

```
public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        if(fi.FullName.StartsWith(m_root_a))
            return fi.FullName.SubString(m_root_a.Length).GetHashCode();
        else if(fi.FullName.StartsWith(m_root_b))
            return fi.FullName.SubString(m_root_b.Length).GetHashCode();
        else
            throw Exception("Invalid File. This file is not a part of the directories compared.");
    }
```

---

**Update**

Based on comment from @Rufus

as per the specified article at [CA1065: Do not raise exceptions in unexpected locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1065?view=vs-2019)
it states that

GetHashCode Methods: `Object.GetHashCode` and `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(Object)` method should "usually" not throw exceptions.

1. **GetHashCode should always return a value. Otherwise, you can lose items in the hash table.**
2. *The versions of GetHashCode that take an argument can throw an ArgumentException. **However, Object.GetHashCode should never throw
   an exception.***

***BUT***

If I am developing this application and to **make sure** that only files from specified directories are compared, I would definitely throw an Exception.

- If a developer knowingly or unknowingly compares files from two different folders one or both of which were not used why initializing the object, then the file comparison is totally invalid.
- Also, `GetHashCode` method returns an `int` while Windows allows `uint` (4x10^10) number of files. And if someone (who knows?) try to break the code, there will definitely be a hash collision and hence false matches; and I don't like to take such chances.

Instead I will be OK with losing the Hashtable, showing an error message to the user/developer and asking him/her to start again.

Comment: Thank you for answer! To be consistent I assume that should extend your code with fi.Length `return (fi.FullName.Substring(m_root_a.Length) + fi.Length.ToString()).GetHashCode();` etc.

Comment: Probably shouldn't throw an exception from `GetHashCode`, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1065?view=vs-2019

Comment: @CreekDrop: Yeah, great idea for faster comparisons, but on revisiting your algorithm and reading the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode I find hash comparison might not be as helpful as it seems. The documentation states : `Note that it is NOT a rule that if two objects have the same hash code, then they must be equal.`

Comment: You may instead use SHA256, but then you may need to store the past generated hashes for a file (may be create your own FileInfo class to store that). Just a thought...